# How to draw lines consisting of repeating images in (Py)GTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, cairo, gtk2

I am currently writing a Python program on Linux using the pygtk library. I already managed to make the windows background transparent and pass all clicks to the windows below my window. So now I have got an invisible window which would do nothing since any click and key events will be forwarded to the window below.

Now I would like to use an external program / device that tells my program where to draw lines. I already managed to do so.

But what is the right and most efficient way to draw a line onto the screen / window consisting of repeating single images. Let's say I've got a part of a laser line (8x8 pixels) and now I want to draw a line from coordinates (0,0) to (20,12) and then maybe to (22, 15), then to (25, 15) and so on. The user will paint it.

My final question is: how do I draw a line textured with a small repeated single png image given many coordinates the user draws onto the window (which looks like the screen because its background is invisible)?

Comment: As a side-note: don't use pygtk. It's the old static binding meant for GTK+ 2. But it's 2017 and GTK+ 3 has been there for years. Please read the python + GTK+ 3 tutorial: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: As for the drawing, you're supposed to do that with cairo: https://cairographics.org

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [GooCanvas](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GooCanvas). This library (built on the drawing tools from Gdk/Gtk - Cairo) takes care of much of the details of drawing the items, and also takes care of automatic redrawing. You can draw lines using textures, images etc. Also, you can define handlers on events of each layer, and each element drawn.

The result is a widget, which can be packed anywhere in the GUI. Look for not GooCanvas 2.0.x - not the old 1.x strain. It can be used in Python through introspection.

You can set the fill-color to a pixbuf (not directly a PNG, but easily convertible)